# Cannot use spring-integration security with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying to use Spring Integration Security configuration inside of Spring Boot application, in the following way:

```
<si-security:secured-channels access-decision-manager=
"accessDecisionManager">
    <si-security:access-policy pattern="requestChannel" receive-access="ROLE_USER"/>
</si-security:secured-channels>
```

This XML configuration is inserted into the following configuration class:

```
package demo.security.config;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDecisionManager;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDecisionVoter;
import org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased;
import org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter;

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
// mentioned Spring Integration Security Config causing
// java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to
// configure default servlet handling
@ImportResource({"classpath:springIntegrationSecurity.xml"})
public class SpringIntegrationSecurity {

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Bean
public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
    RoleVoter roleVoter = new RoleVoter(); 
    roleVoter.setRolePrefix("");
    final AffirmativeBased acd = new AffirmativeBased(Arrays.<AccessDecisionVoter> 
        asList(roleVoter));
    return acd;
}
```

}

If I include mentioned Spring Integration Security XML configuration into my application it crashes with:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
```

It seems that Spring Security Integration config is loaded before ServletContext, but I don't know howto overcome this problem...:(

My pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.test</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-integration-security</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>spring-integration-security</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Can someone help please? If I omit Spring Integration Security my application works fine...

Comment: Why not use pure java configuration without xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may be with the order for `@ImportResource` resolution. That's why in most cases Spring Boot requires the Java Config for everything.

For example your Spring Integration Security case can be represented like:

```
@Bean
@SecuredChannel(interceptor = "channelSecurityInterceptor", receiveAccess = "ROLE_USER")
public MessageChannel requestChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public ChannelSecurityInterceptor channelSecurityInterceptor(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager) {
    ChannelSecurityInterceptor channelSecurityInterceptor = new ChannelSecurityInterceptor();
    channelSecurityInterceptor.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    channelSecurityInterceptor.setAccessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager);
    return channelSecurityInterceptor;
}
```

From other side, please, share with the Spring Boot and Spring Integration versions you use.

And would you mind to check the same with the latest Spring Boot 1.3 M5?

Comment: Hi Artem,  I have upgraded to spring-boot 1.3 M5 and rewritten spring integration security XML config to Java config as you suggested and it works like a charm! Thanks a lot...Just one additional question, I still had to configure accessDecisionManager, why spring-boot-starter-security doesn't expose accessDecisionManager as SpringBean?